# How do I get a dishwasher to fit with pipes in the way?

Tags: kitchens, pipe, dishwasher

The installer showed up with the new dishwasher ([KitchenAid KDTM404EWH](http://www.sears.com/kitchenaid-kdtm404ewh-24inch-top-control-built-in-dishwasher/p-02214372000P)).  Once he took the old one out, he found that these pipes are in the way:

[image: Picture of pipes under counter where dishwasher needs to go]

Any ideas about what I can do? The installer said I'd need a dishwasher with a depth no greater than 19.25 inches.  That seems small to me. Do they make dishwashers like that?

---

### Additional Details

Here's a picture of the space with measurements:

[image: Picture of the space with measurements]

Here are the details:

```
    | Measurement                                                       | Value  |
    |-------------------------------------------------------------------|--------|
    | Full height of opening                                            | 34.5"  |
    | Full width of opening                                             | 24.5"  |
    | Full depth of space                                               | 24.0"  |
    | Distance from front of pipes to back wall                         | 4.75"  |
    | Height of pipes                                                   | 3"     |
    | Width of pipes                                                    | 6"     |
    | Full width of opening - width of pipes                            | 18.5"  |
    | Full depth of opening - distance from front of pipes to back wall | 19.25" |
    | Full height of opening - height of pipes                          | 31.5"  |
```

Comment: The added information you have provided and the pictures sure do help tell a more in depth story. The options I listed below all still apply. I just want to ensure you understand that the purpose of the site is to help solve home improvement questions, not perform product research (to find a dishwasher that fits the space). So my answer #4 doesn't change. Seeing the sink location, it makes #3 a no go. #6 & #2 really isn't a possibility either. So #1, #5, & #4 are your best choices in that order. You seem to want #4 but I suspect in the long run you are going to be very unhappy with #4.

Comment: Moving the pipes looks like a pain the first photo looks to have a T going into the slab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So we found a dishwasher that fit. It's an ADA compliant [Frigidaire 24" FDB2410HIS](https://www.frigidaire.com/Kitchen-Appliances/Dishwashers/Dishwasher/FDB2410HIS/). It's not the fanciest dishwasher, but it gets the dishes clean.

Answer (score 1):

What can you do?:

1. Move the pipes: This is ideal, because that is .... UGH.
2. Move the/a/some cabinets: reconfigure the counter arrangements such that the pipes are behind/under a cabinet
3. Raise your counter in this area, trim it off up top and box in a platform on the bottom, so the dishwasher can be mounted above the pipes
4. Find a short tub dishwasher with a rather open back. There are hundreds of dishwashers on the market, you could find one, but knowing how they are framed, it is very very unlikely.
5. Don't install the dishwasher here, put some other device here, and locate the dishwasher somewhere else. (same basic idea as #2) but leave cabinets where they are, put a garbage can here
6. Cut a cabinet down, re-frame it (customize the cabinet) to allow room to the right to mount the dishwasher

I vote for #1, because what you have here is just, unpleasant. But these are "all" of the things you can do that I can creatively dream up.

Comment: Move the pipe furthest out, as far over as you can. Then move your cabinet filler blank (right side panel) to the left side. This should give you an extra 3", however, you would also need to make sure that any cabinet doors or drawers will not interfere with the dishwasher. From what I can see in the picture, this shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Well, you are still indicating to move the pipe, even if only one. So might as well spend the time and money to move both (if needed) to get a standard DW installed. In the long run, there will be no more limit on size/style of DW to purchase/use and there will be no visual damage or futzing with cabinetry work.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to find a dishwasher that will fit there without moving the pipes. The back left of many dishwashers don't have anything there, so at the worst you would just have to modify the support/frame depending on the specific model of dishwasher you purchase. The image of a typical dishwasher below shows how the back is mostly empty space on some models.

So you might be able to buy a different dishwasher that will fit without doing any extra work!

[image: Typical dishwasher]